# Создать div и определить его через getElementById

Tags: jquery

Возможно ли через `createElement` создать такой `div`, чтобы его потом мог определить `getElementById`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let main = document.querySelector('#extra_menu');
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = "index_1";
    div.innerHTML = "Hello";
    main.append(div);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="extra_menu"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var click_1 = document.getElementById('index_1');

click_1.onclick = function() {
    click_1.attr("style", "color: red");
}
```

Comment: Да, это возможно

Comment: А как? Я делаю по макету выше и все время 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null'

Comment: А вы покажите весь код. тогда и продолжить можно разговор детально)

Comment: и скажите, почему метка у вопроса `jquery`, а код на чистом js? что из этого надо?

Comment: Добавил еще часть кода. Разве append это JS?

Comment: "Разве append это JS? " --- вы получаете элемент через нативный метод `querySelector`. Поэтому да. (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)

Answer (score 0):

Элемента ещё нет на странице, когда вы прикрепляете к нему слушателя. Можно сделать так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let main = document.querySelector('#extra_menu');
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = "index_1";
    div.innerHTML = "Hello";
    div.addEventListener("click", test);
   
    main.append(div);
});

let test = function() {
    this.style.color = 'red';    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extra_menu"></div>
```

---

Либо использовать делегирование

Comment: А можно ли в addEventListener сделать так?
div.addEventListener("click", 'index_' + click_id);

Comment: @Vanya в коде `div.addEventListener` итак навешивается событие клика на тот элемент, который доблавляется. Поэтому это `'index_' + click_id` не имеет смысла. Либо надо было сформулировать изначально задачу, которую решаете.

Comment: Хотел, чтобы в div.addEventListener("click", 'index_1); была рандомная цифра после index_

Comment: @Vanya зачем? какая задача? Возможно надо рандом надо делать на уровне `div.id = "index_1";`.   а вообще, по опыту, тех, кто делает айдишники в формате `element-1/element-2/element-3....element-N` делают что-то не так. И им достаточно общего класса

Comment: Да. Это нужно для id. Изначально использовал его, так как для поиска пытался использовать getElementById. Но в вашем примере сделано через addEventListener. Как вывод, мне нужно теперь рандом сделать тут.

Comment: да. используйте `let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
  div.id = "index_" + Math.round(rand);`

Comment: А такое можно сделать для addEventListener?

Comment: @Vanya зачем? какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: У меня в файле прописан click для id от index_1 до index_10. В другом файле создается элемент div с рандомным index_ числом.
Тут вы скорей всего предложите прописать 10 div и через цикл скрыть не нужные, но мне нужно именно создавать div с рандомным id. Но для всех возможных id прописаны click. 
Проблема только в том, что элемент, который был создан через jquery, не виден getElementById.

Comment: а это важно, что это всё прописано в разных файлах? в общем решается это пока так: создаётся массив с номерами, по которым можно кликать `let arr = [1, 5, 7];`. Дальше создаётся функция генерации дива с рандомным идентификатором (писал выше) и если он входит в массив `if (array.includes(generatedId));`, то вешаем слушателя.

Comment: Вот у меня в проекте так и сделано. Элемент с нужным именем id создается. Но getElementById не хочет его видеть.

Comment: причём тут getElementById? Берите код выше и применяйте то, что я написал в комменте

Comment: Так я использовал id, что его находил getElementById. Для id можно сгенерировать любое имя через jquery. Вы сделали пример через addEventListener. А в нем же нельзя сгенерировать второй параметр.

Comment: @Vanya вы не поняли https://jsfiddle.net/3tkgr2wa/

Comment: Только зачем мне уже id, когда клик будет выполняться через addEventListener. У меня заранее прописано несколько кликов. А созданный див, должен вызвать одну из click функций.

Comment: Ладно, я ничего не понял, что вы странное делаете и хотите)))

Comment: Решил проблему. Оставил как в своем шаблоне, только файл с функциями на клик поставил на таймаут.

Comment: Ужасное решение проблемы